# Creating function to count characters in a string

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a function to count the occurrences of a letter within a string. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
   function charCount ($str, $char){
       for($i=0;$i <= strlen($str);$i++){
           if($str[$i] == $char){
           echo $char;
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php
  $string = charCount ("This is a test", "t");
  echo "$string";
?>
```

The output should just be a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function charCount ($str, $char){
   $count=0;
   for($i=0;$i < strlen($str);$i++){
       if($str[$i] == $char){
           $count++;
        }   
    }
    return $count;
}
```

In the for loop must count to the length of the string minus 1, so it is used:
`$i < strlen($str);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   function charCount ($str, $char){
     $count = 0;
       for($i=0;$i <= strlen($str);$i++){
           if($str[$i] == $char){
           ++$count;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
?>

<?php
  $str = "This is a test";
  $char = "t";
  $string = charCount($str, $char);
  echo $string;

  // Another way to do this

  $number = substr_count($str, $char);
  echo $number;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use the in-build PHP function [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

**Note:** *For case insensitive search, convert $text to lower case and then apply function*

```
$text = "This is a test";
$search = "t";
echo substr_count(strtolower($text), $search); // Case insensitive search. Prints 3.

echo substr_count($text, $search); // Case sensitive search. Prints 2.
```